# Choose a Git Repository / Source Directory through Choose Sources instead of Source Jar

Tags: java, git, maven, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I am using a library whose build process does not deploy a sources artifact to the maven repository it is located in. Modifying the build process it out of my control.

However, I have access to the git repository for the library (and thus its sources). I could also clone this repository to my local computer. Is there anyway to point IntelliJ to the sources for the library through either specifying the git repository, or local directory, rather than a sources jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have IntelliJ 2019.2.3 and `Choose Sources` says:

> Select JAR/ZIP files **or directories** in which library sources are located

I've tested this with a directory and it works just fine.  IF you ever need to change the choice you made then it's in File -> Project Structure -> Libraries